# Why don't these columns line up?

Tags: css, css-position, multiple-columns

I'm facing with a strange problem I can't pinpoint. I have a 3 column layout where the first 2 columns have position-fixed, so that only the third column scrolls.

The first element of each column have a margin-top of 20px (for the first and third column it's the H1 element, for the second column it's the div). For some reason, the third column does not line up with the first 2.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <h1>Sidebar</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="mediablock">
                    Media here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Content goes here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have a simple version of it at jsfiddle, demonstrating the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/59ez7zmy/

I can only assume that the position-fixed has got something to do with it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

When I use the Chrome developer toolbar, there is a (approx) 20px gap (although not defined by any margin) between the top of the page and the divs, and the elements inside the position: fixed columns have a 20px margin relative to the container2 div (as expected). The third column however, has a 20px margin to the top of the screen rather than the .container2 div.

Anyone knows what I'm missing here?

Comment: Position fixed means that those objects wont move when you scroll, you might want to find an alternative solution if that's not what you're going for.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish. .sidebar and .menu should not scroll, only .content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `top: 0` for `.sidebar` and `.menu` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59ez7zmy/1/)).

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
    top: 0;
}
```

<sub>See the documentation for [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)</sub>

Comment: Updated your JSFiddle to reflect the requirements that the right column scrolls... http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/59ez7zmy/3/

Comment: Perfect, it works! I knew it had to be something simple, just couldn't put my finger on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add `position: fixed` on `.content` class:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
  text-align: right;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
}
.content {
  margin-left: 370px;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
}
.mediablock {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.container2 {
  width: 550;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="mediablock">
          Media here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Content goes here</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also if you don't want to use `position: fixed` you can use `display: inline-block` also in `.content` class:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
    text-align: right;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(97, 68, 50);
}
.content {
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.mediablock {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.container2 {
    width: 550;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="sidebar">
                 <h1>Sidebar</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="mediablock">Media here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                 <h1>Content goes here</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Also you have some errors in your css i fix them.

Comment: I believe the intention of the OP was specifically to not have the `content` pane fixed. The left two columns should stay fixed while `content` scrolls.

Comment: Indeed, the third column should be able to scroll, as this will contain the mayority of the text of the pages.